# apply Yii::app()->language in all site view

Tags: php, yii

i use yii .. and  i want to make bottom in my site which change language from Arabic to English

it doesn't work for me
when i click .. i will let it go function and do this for all my view

but now this function doesn't work

```
public function actionLanguage()
 //This function to change language
{
    $lang = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('lang');
    if($lang=='ar') {Yii::app()->language='ar'; $this->redirect(array('site/index'));}
    if($lang=='en') {Yii::app()->language='en'; $this->redirect(array('site/index'));}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following code to change the language. I have a `language` action that saves the language to the session. And then on every pageload I set the app language to the session language.

```
 public function actionLanguage($lang) {
    Yii::app()->session['_lang'] = $lang;
    $this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->getUrlReferrer());
 }
```

In my `Controller.php` (all other controllers extend this controller) I overrule the `init()` function to set the languge.

```
 public function init() {
    parent::init();

    $app = Yii::app();
    if (isset($app->session['_lang'])) {
        $app->language = $app->session['_lang'];
    }
 }
```